# Can't figure out integral bounds

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am looking at this solution and I don't understand where $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ integral bounds come from?

$$A=2b\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}dx$$

Do the change of variable $\sin \theta=\frac{x}{a}\implies \theta=\sin^{-1}(x/a)$
$$\cos\theta d\theta=(1/a)dx\implies dx=a\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2}$$

So we have:

$$A=2ab\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta$$
$$A=ab\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(1+\cos2\theta) d\theta$$
$$A=ab\left[\theta+\frac12\sin2\theta\right]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$$
$$A=ab(\pi/2+0+\pi/2-0)$$
$$A=\pi ab$$

Comment: Folks here *will* downvote you (despite what you request) if you insist on posting images, which cannot be searched.  Take the time and show the courtesy to people who might want to help you.

Comment: You been here long enough to use MathJax, don't you think?

Comment: See [Integration by substitution#Definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the substitution

$$\theta(x)=\sin^{-1}(x/a)$$
and the limits $x=\pm a$, you get the limits for $\theta$

$$\theta(\pm a)=\sin^{-1}(\pm 1)= \pm \frac\pi2$$